# The Laplacian operator is invariant to $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform, automorphic-forms

I am reading Iwaniec's book on the spectral analysis of automorphic forms, where I bumped into the following statement in p.20 section 1.6.

Given a function $f:\mathbb{H}\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$, having continuous second derivatives, and some $g\in SL_2(\mathbb{R})$, then $\Delta(f(gz)) = (\Delta f)(gz)$.

Note that the Laplacian operator we use on the hyperbolic plane $\mathbb{H}$, is $$\Delta = y^2(\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2})$$

My idea is that in order to prove such a statement, it is enough to prove it over the generators of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$, i.e., it is enough to check that the identity holds for $g_t(z) = z + t$ for $t\in\mathbb{R}$, and $g^*(z) = -\dfrac{1}{z}$. I found it easy proving the statement for $g=g_t$, however for $g^*$ I didn't understand why it is true that:

$$\Delta(f(-\dfrac{1}{z})) = (\Delta f)(-\dfrac{1}{z})$$

Writing down the formulas for the Laplacian, we get that the LHS is equal to:
$$y^2(\dfrac{\partial^2 (f\circ\dfrac{-1}{z})}{\partial x^2} + \dfrac{\partial^2 (f\circ\dfrac{-1}{z})}{\partial y^2})$$
Whereas the RHS equals:
$$\Im(-\dfrac{1}{z})^2(\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(\dfrac{-1}{z}) + \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(\dfrac{-1}{z}))$$

I could continue with the computation, however, simply analyzing the coefficient of $$\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(\dfrac{-1}{z})$$ on both sides seems to show me that I am on the wrong path. For the LHS:

$$y^2\cdot\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(-\dfrac{1}{z})\dfrac{\partial^2 (-\dfrac{1}{z})}{\partial x^2}$$

For the RHS I obtain:

$$\Im(-\dfrac{1}{z})^2\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(\dfrac{-1}{z})$$

Hence the identity could potentially be true if one has the equality:
$$\Im(-\dfrac{1}{z})^2 = y^2\dfrac{\partial^2 (-\dfrac{1}{z})}{\partial x^2}$$

However, the RHS is $\dfrac{-2y^2}{z^3}$, whereas the LHS is: $\dfrac{y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$, we cannot expect equality in the general case, so I am confused.

Answer (score 4):

$$(\Delta f)(z)= y^2(f_{xx}(z)+f_{yy}(z))$$

$u(z)=-1/z,g(z)=f(u(z))$

$$g_x(z) = \Re(u_x(z))f_x(u(z))+\Im(u_x(z))f_y(u(z))$$
$$g_{xx}(z) = \Re(u_{xx}(z))f_x(u(z)) + \Re(u_x(z))^2 f_{xx}(u(z))+\Re(u_x(z))\Im(u_x(z)) f_{xy}(u(z))\\
+
\Im(u_{xx}(z))f_y(u(z)) + \Re(u_x(z))\Im(u_x(z)) f_{yx}(u(z))+\Im(u_x(z))^2 f_{yy}(u(z))
$$

$$g_y(z) = \Re(u_y(z))f_x(u(z))+\Im(u_y(z))f_y(u(z))$$

$$g_{yy}(z) = \Re(u_{yy}(z))f_x(u(z)) + \Re(u_y(z))^2 f_{xx}(u(z))+\Re(u_y(z))\Im(u_y(z)) f_{xy}(u(z))\\
+
\Im(u_{yy}(z))f_y(u(z)) + \Re(u_y(z))\Im(u_y(z)) f_{yx}(u(z))+\Im(u_y(z))^2 f_{yy}(u(z))
$$

The point is that
$u_{xx}(z)=-u_{yy}(z)$ and $ \Re(u_x(z))\Im(u_x(z)) = \Re(-i u_y(z))\Im(-iu_y(z))= -\Re(u_y(z))\Im(u_y(z)) $ so you get

$$\boxed{g_{xx}(z)+g_{yy}(z)=(\Re(u_x(z))^2+\Re(u_y(z))^2) f_{xx}(u(z))+
(\Im(u_x(z))^2+\Im(u_y(z))^2) f_{yy}(u(z))}$$
You'll find that $$\Re(u_x(z))^2+\Re(u_y(z))^2=\frac1{|z|^4} = \frac{\Im(-1/z)^2}{y^2}=\Im(u_x(z))^2+\Im(u_y(z))^2$$ and hence $$(\Delta g)(z) = (\Delta f)(-1/z)$$

Comment: Do you mind explaining in the first line, we have that $g_x(z)=u_x(z)f_x(u(z))$ by the chain rule, from my understanding, you are trying to split this up into the real and imaginary parts, but I am confused on why when you go to the imaginary part does if become $\text{Im}(u_x(z))f_y(u(z))$?

Comment: Well no, the chain rule is what I wrote. $g_x(z)$ is the directional derivative of $f$ at $-1/z$ in direction $1/z^2$

Comment: I am a bit confused we have that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is the directional derivative in the $x$ direction. Now we are looking at $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(u(z))$, then shouldn't the chain rule give $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(z)\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}u(z)$. Now you saying that this should be the directional derivative of $f$ at $\frac{-1}{z}$ in the direction $\frac{1}{z^2}$ why would it be in the $\frac{1}{z^2}$ direction?

Comment: For $t$ real small, say assuming $f$ is $C^2$ $$f(-1/(z+t)) =f(-1/z+t/z^2+O(t^2))\\=f(-1/z+t/z^2)+O(t^2)=f(-1/z)+t D_{1/z^2}f(-1/z)+O(t^2)\\=f(-1/z)+t\Re(1/z^2) f_x(-1/z)+t\Im(1/z^2) f_y(-1/z) +O(t^2)$$

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate it, I am just trying to understand this. I think there may be an error in the third line of $g_{xx}$ when trying to mimic your calculations, I got $\Im(u_{xx}(z))f_y(u(z))$ rather than $f_x$. This might be a typo, or I may still not be understanding.

Comment: Yes a typo, sorry. Also note that [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%5E2*%28D%5BD%5Bf%28-x%2F%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%2Cy%2F%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%29%2Cx%5D%2Cx%5D%2BD%5BD%5Bf%28-x%2F%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%2Cy%2F%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%29%2Cy%5D%2Cy%5D%29) immediately gives the result in its "alternate form" answer

Comment: Thanks so much for all the help.

Comment: Out of interest, I have found one instance in the literature where this calculation is actually carried out (though in a more abbreviated form than @reuns' above): on page 2 of Motohashi's *Spectral Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function*. Their calculation in full is $$\begin{align*} \Delta f(x, y)&=-y^2 (u_x^2 + v_x^2)(F_{uu} + F_{vv}) \\&=-y^2 \bigl\lvert \frac{d}{d z} \gamma(z) \bigr\rvert^2 (F_{uu} + F_{vv}) = -v^2(F_{uu} + F_{vv}), \end{align*}$$ where $f(x, y) = F(u, v)$ and $\gamma(x + i y) = u + i v$, and they point out that in doing so we use the Cauchy-Riemann equation for $\gamma(z)$.

Answer (score 2):

I think not so many people have ever followed that computation through to the end! :)  Ok, so you can see @reuns' good version of it.

Still, I would seriously suggest that we'd want to "somehow" know a-priori that that expression was $SL_2(\mathbb R)$ invariant, rather than be told or have an epiphany that it must be so.

Yes, if we believe already in the *existence* of an $SL_2(\mathbb R)$-invariant second-order operator (annihilating constants), then already the subgroup $\pmatrix{* & * \cr 0 & *}$ happens to determine the form of it.

But, perhaps, after a certain point in one's life, a more intrinsic and coordinate-independent "characterization" of Casimir/Laplacian might be desirable... so that one can determine what it is in any particular coordinate system, while knowing a-priori that it is invariant. That is, instead of guessing a thing in coordinates and checking its invariance, we characterize an invariant thing and then determine what it is in some given coordinates.

The standard one-line description of a $G$-invariant second-order diffop (Casimir) on a semi-simple real Lie group is obtained from a diagram of $G$-equivariant maps:
$$
\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb C}(\mathfrak g)
\;\approx\;
\mathfrak g\otimes \mathfrak g^*
\;\approx\; \mathfrak g\otimes \mathfrak g
\;\subset\;A\mathfrak g
\;\to\; U\mathfrak g
$$
where the first is the general linear algebra isomorphism, the second is the isomorphism of $\mathfrak g$ with its dual via the Killing form, $A\mathfrak g$ is the universal *associative* algebra generated by $\mathfrak g$ (also called "the tensor algebra"), and the last map is the quotient to the universal enveloping algebra. The identity endomorphism of $\mathfrak g$ is $G$-invariant/equivariant, so its image in $U\mathfrak g$ is, also. That image is the Casimir operator, which descends to the invariant Laplacian on $G/K$...

The identity map in the endomorphism algebra is immediately identifiable with $\sum_i x_i\otimes x_i^*$ for any basis $x_i$ of $\mathfrak g$, with dual basis $x_i^*$. An astute choice of these gives the in-coordinates expression of the invariant Laplacian on $\mathfrak H$... knowing a-priori that whatever expression comes out is $G$-invariant. :)

Comment: For a (very explicit!) example of the calculation of the in-coordinates expression carried in this way, the reader may consult Section 2.3 of Goldfeld's *Automorphic Forms and L-Functions for the Group GL(n, R)*. In the beginning of the same chapter (p. 39) we also find the apposite quote "It is not so obvious that the operator $-y^2 (\partial^2/\partial x^2 + \partial^2/\partial y^2)$ is invariant under the discrete group actions $z \mapsto \frac{a z + b}{c z + d}$." :)

Comment: @prets, yes, thanks for that ref. Also, in the first of my two volumes "Modern Analysis of Automorphic Forms by Example" (Cambridge... but/and on-line at my web site) I do some related computations, as well, after a discussion of the intrinsic aspect. :)